# Updating a Database Joined view in only 1 base table

Tags: sql, database, join, view, sybase

I have a database view which is made up of joining 2 base tables, say table 1, table 2.
I want to ensure that, whenever, and update or an insert is called on the view, it only updates the columns of table 1, and leave the columns of table 2 to NULL.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, If you want to update or insert via db view that view should be created using **only one table**. Consider below example, please.

Preparing tables `tab` and `tab2`

```
create table tab
   (
      id int
   )

    create table tab2
   (
      id int
   )
```

Preparing tables `vtab` and `vtabboth`. `vtabboth` has a `join`

```
   create view vtab
   as
   select * from tab

   create view vtabboth
   as
   select t.id as tid ,t2.id as t2id from tab t
   join tab2 t2 on t.id = t2.id
```

Below insert will work

```
   insert into vtab
   values (1)
```

Bellow insert

```
   insert into vtabboth
   values (1,1)
```

will rise an error:

> View 'vtabboth' is not updatable because the FROM clause names
>   multiple tables.